# Listener hanging not able to status

Tags: oracle

I am having an issue across all databases on 3 separate environments. Database, listener, application on same local machine. Basic simple listener.ora, tnsnames.ora with one SID/service name. I used DBCA to create database years ago and netca to configure listener etc.

This has been running seemingly without tons of issues until recently but there have been many connection timeouts, socket errors. It seems the listener does not remain up and stable.

I can start the listener; however, after the initial start and maybe a status, the listener hangs on a status. Occasionally the listener will complete after a while but more often, I grep for it and kill the PID.

Two things (sqlnet.ora and pfile init file) that I notice are missing but am unsure if this is an issue because this was a functioning system. I added both and it didn’t seem to make any progress.

Of course I can connect directly to the database but when I go to through the listener I get an error:

```
bin]$ ./sqlplus sys/xxxx@cosga as sysdba
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Mon Feb 27 22:21:39 2017
Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
ERROR:
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact
```

Listener.ora:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: /app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = server fully qualifed)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /app/oracle
```

Tnsnames.ora:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: /app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.
COSGA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = server fullyqualified)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = cosga)
    )
  )
```

Tnsping

```
$ ./tnsping cosga
TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 27-FEB-2017 22:28:41
Copyright (c) 1997, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Used parameter files:
Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = server fully qualified)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = cosga)))
TNS-12547: TNS:lost contact
```

Etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx  serverfullyqualified server
```

Show parameters (removed possibly not applicable):

```
SQL> show parameters;
audit_file_dest  /app/oracle/admin/cosga/adump
background_dump_dest  /app/oracle/diag/rdbms/cosga/cosga/trace
bitmap_merge_area_size  1048576
compatible  11.2.0.0.0
control_file_record_keep_time  7
control_files  /app/oracle/oradata/cosga/control01.ctl, /app/oracle/flash_recovery_area/cosga/control02.ctl
core_dump_dest  /app/oracle/diag/rdbms/cosga/cosga/cdump
create_bitmap_area_size   8388608
db_files      200
db_name   cosga
db_recovery_file_dest  /app/oracle/flash_recovery_area
db_recovery_file_dest_size  3882M
db_unique_name  cosga
dg_broker_config_file1  /app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/dbs/dr1cosga.dat
dg_broker_config_file2  /app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/dbs/dr2cosga.dat
diagnostic_dest  /app/oracle
dispatchers  (PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=cosgaXDB)
distributed_lock_timeout  60
hash_area_size    131072
ifile  file
instance_name  cosga
job_queue_processes  1000
max_enabled_roles  150
memory_max_target  7G
memory_target     7G
open_cursors      300
open_links    4
open_links_per_instance   4
processes     300
resource_manager_cpu_allocation  4
resumable_timeout  0
service_names  cosga
session_cached_cursors  50
session_max_open_files  10
sessions      472
sga_max_size      7G
sga_target    0
shared_pool_reserved_size 144284057
standby_archive_dest  ?/dbs/arch
transactions      519
transactions_per_rollback_segment   5
undo_tablespace  UNDOTBS1
user_dump_dest  /app/oracle/diag/rdbms/cosga/cosga/trace
```

Status listener:

```
]$ ./lsnrctl status listener
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 27-FEB-2017 18:30:46
Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=servername.fullyqualified)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-01153: Failed to process string: ����
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? At this point it is affecting the vendor application at this major corporation. Not only will the tomee server not start if the listener is not operating correctly but we and the vendor believe it is the source for performance and capacity issues of the SLM interface.

At one point this was working very well, even auto starting from a reboot with dbora, apache, tomee etc.

Comment: your listener.ora mentions "(HOST = server fully qualifed)". I hope you have entered your server name there, and not this exact string. Because that will not work.

Comment: Does the IP address in your /etc/hosts file (which you've hidden as xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) match (a) the actual interface address on the server - which you can see with `netstat`; and (b) the address returned by `dig +short serverfullyqualified` (using your real server name, of course; it would be slightly less confusing if you had replaced your real FQDN with something like `myserver.example`, and consistently in all the files and commands).?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. "server fully qualified is the actual server name like myserver.example. Sorry, I've never posted on a forum so I am unfamilar with the format, thank you. I am stumped on this one. The IP address matches everywhere it should including etc/host. We've even traced network dumps that are on 1521 and they come and go like they should. That is why this is has us stumped and I reached out. The listener starts just fine, you can run status the first time but every time after it hangs. It was all working and I made no changes

Answer (score 2):

Your listener log file might be too big. Try renaming it so a new one gets created in its place.

```
$ORACLE_BASE\diag\tnslsnr\<hostname>\listener\trace\<listener_name>.log
```